# What is a Module, and what is an R-module? (understanding the definition)

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory, modules

So, I am trying to imagine what a Module and R-module look like, and what kind of elements are in these structures.

For a Module, it's analogous to a ring of a vector space over a field. So can I think of a Module as a set of vectors? And the entries of the vectors are in the field? What is the general way I think of a module?

For an $R-module$, let $R$ be a ring. An $R-module$ $V$ is an abelian group with addition and scalar multiplication. This means, we have a set of vectors that can be scaled by elements in $R$, and are closed under addition?

This is an example of the module I was reading about, but I don't think I'm imagining the structure correctly. If someone can clarify, that would be great.

$R = C[x,y]$ and $M$ is the ideal of $R$ generated by two elements $x$ and $y$.

Initially I thought, since a module is a set of vectors, M would be some vectors of length 1, because an ideal is a set containing polynomials. But that seems to be incorrect.

Comment: It seems your understanding of vectors themselves is a bit myopic. Vectors do not, in general, have "entries." *Coordinate* vectors have entries, but in general vectors are just elements of a vector space. Furthermore, vectors do not, in general, have "length." The notion of length is very particular to certain vector spaces - for example, real inner product spaces, or complex Hilbert spaces, etc. Also, an ideal is not "a set containing numbers." If the elements of a ring are numbers, then ideals contain numbers, but elements of rings are not numbers in general.

Comment: My bad! for the ideal, it should be a set of polynomials with coefficients in c. But that means a vector is a polynomial?

Comment: "Vector" means "element of a vector space," and "vector space" means an abelian group with scalar multiplication from some field. The set of polynomials form an abelian group with scalar multiplication, so form a vector space, in which case its elements (polynomials) are vectors.

Comment: Sometimes the name vector is dicieving. As arctic tern indicated: a vector is just an element of a set that satisfy the axioms of vector spaces. It might help to rename/think of vector space as linear space that has two operations: addition and multiplications by scalars. Again the name scalar might be dicieving. It doesnt mean that scalars have to be numbers! The set of real valued continous functions over [0,1] for example form a linear space over the reals. A function which is an element of this space is called a vector in the space.

Comment: You can think of a Module as a vector (linear) space however the set of scalars is not a field. Instead it is a ring. So what actually makes the difference here is the set of scalars and what kind of operations you can define there.

Comment: A module and an $R$-module are the same thing: the second name just emphasizes the base ring.  In the same way, one can talk about vector spaces, but also talk about a $\mathbb{C}$-vector space (or vector space over $\mathbb{C}$) if one wants to emphasize the base field.

Comment: Thanks so much guys, all those comments are extremely helpful